# React: Can't import .tsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

New to using TypeScript with React. When I import a component that is from a .tsx file, it assumes it is a .js file by default. The error says that there is no About.js file or Contact.js file in that directory. Additionally, the TS linter won't let me add .tsx to the end of the file path. How to fix this? I used 'npx create-react-app project_name --typescript'. Here is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './views/Home'
import About from './views/About'
import Contact from './views/Contact'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Footer from './components/Footer'

const App: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar title="Website" links={['About', 'Contact']} color="blue"/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>

      <Footer/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: you're going to need to provide a few more details. how are you building your app? are you using a starter kit?

Comment: I'm using create-react-app. I did 'npx create-react-app (name) --typescript'

Answer (score 8):

Did you use create react app? In case you didn't use or used and eject it you should add this config to your webpack config file:

```
{
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"],
  },
}
```

In case that you used create react app and didn't eject it you can add these rules to your `typescript-eslint`

```
module.exports = {
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      'node': {
        'extensions': ['.js','.jsx','.ts','.tsx']
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you use create react app or any seed project to bring up your application?

Comment: Yeah I used create react app. I found the extension place he was talking about and added .ts & .tsx so now it's working. thanks

Comment: Yeah I used create react app. I found the extension place he was talking about and added .ts & .tsx so now it's working. thanks

Comment: I used create-react-app app-name --template typescript to create the app and there is no webpack.config.js in the directory.  when I import tsx file it identifies as ts file and compile error says there is no particular ts file. any suggestion that would help me? thanks

Comment: What's `typescript-eslint`?

Comment: I have "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "pages/_document.js"  ] in tsconfig.json and still getting the error

Comment: can you please add details on how did you resolve this problems? I can't find where to add the rules nor the config. 
Would be nice for @IdinKhayami also to specify if the previous answers is the one that helped you to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I used the default create app of react (that create a JS project by default).

1. A temporary solution I used was to add the tsx extension to the import, it compiles and the site works but appears like a compilation error in the IDE
2. The permanent solution was to create a new react app using the typescript template like so:

> npx create-react-app  --template typescript

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
```